# Tiles framework low performance

Tags: performance, tiles, apache-tiles

I built a Spring MVC web app with TilesViewResolver, but the performance is poor, very slow.
In a benchmark Tiles is sevent times slower than JSP.
Is there any way to improve this?

Comment: Depending on DefinitionsFactory and  DefinitionDao you use it is possible that tiles doesnot cache tile definitions. Maybe this is the cause of low perfomance.

Answer (score 3):

Tiles is based on runtime assembly of JSP pages. So at the runtime, the tiles definition is loaded through Tiles configuration, and when a view is rendered, the code goes through the tiles definition to prepare the final output.

This of course is slower than a JSP page rendering scenario, because tiles has some additional stuff to do. If your page is JSP with include directives, it will be compiled to a Java class and it will be much faster.

The idea of using tiles is to have better layouting options compared to pure JSP. But there will be a performance penalty. However, in most of the cases the bottleneck of modern applications is more in database / application logic than view rendering, so this penalty is acceptable with the benifits Tiles provides.